# JavaScript: Display array items after 3 seconds one a time

Tags: javascript, arrays, delay

I have the code segment:

```
var i = 0;

(function loop() {
    text_objects[i].displayText(); 
    if (++i < text_objects.length) {
        setTimeout(loop, 3000);  
    }
})();
```

Which is supposed to display the contents of an array one at a time, separated by 3 seconds. However, when I run the program, I only get the first item, and it sort of just freezes there, without updating and showing the rest of the items in the array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: I tried this in console by replacing `text_objects` and `displayText()` with a an array and `console.log()` and it is working fine.

Comment: There actually isn't anything in the console log. I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: Are you sure it is going into the if block? When you say it "freezes", do you mean the browser locks up, or just that your code seems to stop before you expected?

Comment: The latter. It doesn't show anything after the first element. I will keep looking into it and provide any updates in the future. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: If there is no error in the console then you most likely change `i` or `text_objects` somewhere else in you code. Place a `console.log(i+' '+text_objects.length)` right after your `displayText()` call in `loop`. Show the output of that.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly mentioned by @nnnnnn,

> loop() is a named function expression, and the reference loop should be in scope within the function

Also your code works fine.

```js
var i = 0;

var test = function(value){
  this.text = value;
}

test.prototype.displayText = function(){
  document.write(this.text + "<br/>");
}

var text_objects = [];

for (var j = 0; j<10; j++){ text_objects.push(new test(j)); }

(function loop() {
    text_objects[i].displayText(); 
    if (++i < text_objects.length) {
        setTimeout(loop, 3000);  
    }
})();
```

Alternate approach:

```js
var i = 0;

function loop() {
    document.write(i + "<br/>")
    if (++i < 5) {
        setTimeout(loop, 3000);  
    }
}

loop();
```

Comment: loop() is a named function expression, and the reference `loop` should be in scope within the function - that's normal and correct Javascript behaviour. But if you are going to rewrite it, couldn't you at least make your version do the same thing as the OP's code?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine. Not sure if this is what you expect?

```
var i = 0;

Array.prototype.displayText = function(i) {
    console.log(this[i]);
};

var text_objects = ['1', '2', '3'];

(function loop() {
    text_objects.displayText(i);
    if (++i < text_objects.length) {
        setTimeout(loop, 3000);  
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is my approach to the answer. Hope I helped!

```js
var i = 0;

function loop() {
  text_objects[i].displayText();
  i = i + 1;
  if (i < text_objects.length) {
    setTimeout(loop, 3000);
  };
};
setTimout(loop, 3000);
```